# Unable to retrieve Firebase Realtime Database entries

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently, my data is stored in such structure:

```
Firebase Database 
|__Posts
    |__3Csdsadq931j(Post hash)
      |__1
        |__created: 1623414664 (timestamp)
           message: "Hello"
           msgID: 1
      |__2
        |__created: 1623414667 (timestamp)
           message: "Bye"
           msgID: 2
```

Currently, I have the posted hash of the chatroom. I would like to retrieve the posts by the most recent post, so from msgID 2 to 1.

However, I keep getting this failure message. "**FIREBASE QUERY ERROR: Unable to get latest value for query FQuerySpec**"

Here is my query:

```
// For this example: let postRoomID = "3Csdsadq931j"
let postReference: DatabaseReference = Database.database().reference().child("Posts").child(postRoomID)

postReference.queryOrdered(byChild: "created").queryLimited(toLast: 30).getData {error , snapshot in ...}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think it has to do something with indexing. How to create an index for "created"?